# How to call stopservice() method of Service class from the calling activity class

Tags: android

I am trying to call my service class's stopService() method from my activity.
But I dont know how to access stopservice method from my activity class.
I have the below code but its not working...........

> This is HomeScreen class:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        enablecheck = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.enablecheck);            

        enablecheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(enablecheck.isChecked()){    
                    startService(new Intent(HomeScreen.this, AutoService.class));
                }else
                {
                    stopService(new Intent(HomeScreen.this, AutoService.class));

                }                       
            }

        });

    }
```

> ```
> This is Service Class:
> ```

```
public class AutoService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "AutoService";
    private Timer timer;    
    private TimerTask task;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Auto Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");     

        int delay = 5000; // delay for 5 sec.
        int period = 5000; // repeat every sec.

        timer = new Timer();

        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task = new TimerTask(){
            public void run() 
            {
                System.out.println("done");
            }   
        }, delay, period);


    }


    @Override
    public boolean stopService(Intent name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        timer.cancel();
        task.cancel();
        return super.stopService(name);

    }


}
```

Any suggestion highly appreciable.
Thanks and Regards
Mintu

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555765/stop-service-in-android

Answer (score 65):

In fact to **stopping the service** we must use the method `stopService()` and you are doing in right way:

**Start** service:

```
  Intent myService = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BackgroundSoundService.class);
  startService(myService);
```

**Stop** service:

```
  Intent myService = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BackgroundSoundService.class);
  stopService(myService);
```

if you call `stopService()`, then the method **`onDestroy()`** in the service is called (**NOT the `stopService()` method**):

```
  @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
      timer.cancel();
      task.cancel();    
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate() , service stopped...");
    }
```

**you must implement the `onDestroy()` method!.**

Here is a [**complete example**](https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-Music-in-Background.) including how to start/stop the service.

Comment: what if I want to restart/ resume the service from where it was.

Answer (score 34):

I actually used pretty much the same code as you above. My service registration in the manifest is the following

```
<service android:name=".service.MyService" android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/menuItemStartService" >
                <action android:name="it.unibz.bluedroid.bluetooth.service.MY_SERVICE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

In the service class I created an according constant string identifying the service name like:

```
public class MyService extends ForeGroundService {
    public static final String MY_SERVICE = "it.unibz.bluedroid.bluetooth.service.MY_SERVICE";
   ...
}
```

and from the according Activity I call it with

```
startService(new Intent(MyService.MY_SERVICE));
```

and stop it with

```
stopService(new Intent(MyService.MY_SERVICE));
```

It works perfectly. Try to check your configuration and if you don't find anything strange try to debug whether your stopService get's called properly.

Comment: afaik it' now a security risk to start and stop a service this way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27842430/service-intent-must-be-explicit-intent

Answer (score 5):

That looks like it should stop the service when you uncheck the checkbox. Are there any exceptions in the log? [stopService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#stopService%28android.content.Intent%29) returns a boolean indicating whether or not it was able to stop the service.

If you are starting your service by Intents, then you may want to extend [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) instead of Service. That class will stop the service on its own when it has no more work to do.

**AutoService**

```
class AutoService extends IntentService {
     private static final String TAG = "AutoService";
     private Timer timer;    
     private TimerTask task;

     public onCreate() {
          timer = new Timer();
          timer = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() 
            {
                System.out.println("done");
            }
          }
     }

     protected void onHandleIntent(Intent i) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onHandleIntent");     

        int delay = 5000; // delay for 5 sec.
        int period = 5000; // repeat every sec.


        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, delay, period);
     }

     public boolean stopService(Intent name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        timer.cancel();
        task.cancel();
        return super.stopService(name);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

@Juri

If you add IntentFilters for your service, you are saying you want to expose your service to other applications, then it may be stopped unexpectedly by other applications.

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin you can do this...

Service:

```
class MyService : Service() {
    init {
        instance = this
    }

    companion object {
        lateinit var instance: MyService

        fun terminateService() {
            instance.stopSelf()
        }
    }
}
```

In your activity (or anywhere in your app for that matter):

```
btn_terminate_service.setOnClickListener {
    MyService.terminateService()
}
```

Note: If you have any pending intents showing a notification in Android's status bar, you may want to terminate that as well.