# Start a service in a separate process android

Tags: android, multithreading, service, process

I want to start a service in a separate process (i.e when I go to my Application manager in the settings and then go to running services, it should show my service in a separate process).

My Android Manifest is as follows:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.timerapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name="com.example.timerapp.WorkerThread"
        android:process="com.moizali"></service>
</application>
```

I am starting the service in my MainActivity so obviously when I kill the application the service shuts down as well. Can anyone tell me how to start the service as a different process.

Comment: You may find it more precise to test your results with the adb shell `ps` command or the DDMS process list, as that settings menu display seems to have some odd "user friendly translation".

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Check out the `process` attribute for `service` in `AndroidManifest.xml`. You need to change your `android:process` value to start with a `:`.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html

The relevant section:

> If the name assigned to this attribute begins with a colon (':'), a new process, private to the application, is created when it's needed and the service runs in that process. If the process name begins with a lowercase character, the service will run in a global process of that name, provided that it has permission to do so. This allows components in different applications to share a process, reducing resource usage.

The other answer provided doesn't really answer the question of how to start a service in a separate process.

---

**Defining a Process of a Service**

The `android:process` field defines the name of the process where the service is to run. Normally, all components of an application run in the default process created for the application. However, a component can override the default with its own process attribute, allowing you to spread your application across multiple processes.

If the name assigned to this attribute begins with a colon (':'), the service will run in its own separate process.

```
<service
  android:name="com.example.appName"
  android:process=":externalProcess" />
```

If the process name begins with a lowercase character, the service will run in a global process of that name, provided that it has permission to do so. This allows components in different applications to share a process, reducing resource usage.

Comment: I get an error when I try to bind to the service using this method.

Comment: @TheRealChx101 you cannot directly bind to a service in a different process. You will need to define an Android interface (AIDL). See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42514893/4730000

Comment: What is the use of running in different process? In that case also it is going to be killed when original application gets killed.

Comment: if i am making a AIDL service in another process does it have to called:remote or can i use any name i want ?  android:process=":remote", is this just the common way so we know its remote but it can be any name right ?

Comment: I didn't understand manifest that much - what do write at the place of android:name=" com.example.appName" ok as it says I have to add the name of my app which is  package="com.example.doghowlapp" but when I write doghowlapp it doesn't work

Comment: What permission do you need to run a service in a global process?

Answer (score 28):

Running on a separate process will not solve your problem. I had the same issue and this is a normal behavior of Android. When you start a `Service` (not a Foreground `Service`), even if it is in a separate process, the OS can kill it any time. In your case, if you close the `Activity`(s)/kill the `Application`, the OS will normally close the service even if they are in separate processes. You have two options:

1- Start your service as a [Foreground `Service`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground). In this case the `Service` will not be closed due to almost any condition. Be aware that the foreground service is designed for specific applications and you will have a sticky notification in the notification center and status bar.

2- Make your service as a Start service (not an `IntentService`). Then on the `onStartCommand` of service, return `START_STICKY`. This will tell the OS, if for any reason you need to close the `Service` run it again when you have enough resources. In your case, when the user closes the `Activity`/kill the `Application` the `Service` process will be killed anyway, however it will normally reopen.

Comment: what to use if I am implementing music player? I am using Service but it's closed when I open some heavy apps even when I start using startForeground()

Comment: Start your service as a foreground service. (https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground)

Comment: @Amir what if i create a service in another process but the USER terminates the app (clears the activity stack), will the service still be running ? since the USER terminated and not the OS, im wondering if there is a difference and if the service can continue if user killed the app instead of OS ?

Comment: @j2emanue, First, In android when you create a new process, it would be a sub-process inside the main app process. It is not a separate process like other operation systems. Second, there is no difference,  when the app is killed by user or OS, the all sub-processes would be killed, and then if the situation is according to the answer above, it could start again

Comment: The process gets its own process ID. There is no concept of sub-process as such in android. If you declare "android:process" tag then it will share the process with the existing(if any) process provided both the app are signed with the same certificate.