# How to bind Service if it's in another process?

Tags: android, service, bind

Manifest:

```
 <service android:name="com.example.MainService" android:process=":main_service"/>
```

Trying to bind service in Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    MainService mMainService;

    private boolean mBound;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        bindService(intentForMainService, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
    }

    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                                       IBinder service) {
            MainService.MainServiceBinder binder = (MainService.MainServiceBinder) service;//HERE IS EXCEPTION
            mMainService = (MainService) binder.getService();
            mBound = true;
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            mMainService = null;
            mBound = false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        doUnbindService();
        super.onStop();
    }

    void doUnbindService() {
        if (mBound) {
          unbindService(mConnection);
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.hos.android, PID: 9001
   java.lang.ClassCastException: android.os.BinderProxy cannot be cast to com.example.service.main.MainService$MainServiceBinder
   at com.example.ui.base.BaseServiceActivity$1.onServiceConnected(MainActivity.java:34)
   at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1335)
   at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1352)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
```

But when I delete this **android:process=":main_service"** all works properly

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Step #1: Write [an AIDL file](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html) that describes the interface to be exported by the service that clients can bind to. For the purposes of this answer, I will call this interface `Foo`, and so the AIDL file would be `Foo.aidl`. Note that if the client and service are in separate Android Studio modules that both need the same `Foo.aidl` content.

Step #2: Have your service's binder extend `Foo.Stub` and override the methods on `Foo.Stub`, instead of extending `IBinder`.

Step #3: In your client, in `onServiceConnected()`, convert the raw binder to a `Foo` instance via `Foo.Stub.asInterface(service)`, and `Foo` has the client side of the AIDL-defined API.

[This pair of sample projects](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Binding/Remote) illustrates this, where in my case the client and the service are in separate apps.

Comment: @NickUnuchek: Sorry, but I do not know what you mean.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html ` Process.myPid()`

Comment: @NickUnuchek: First, that is just some sample code. Second, that method is on `android.os.Process`. You have to import that manually, as by default, Java will use `java.lang.Process`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Is AIDL needed even if the service is inside the current app, yet has a different process that it runs on? I mean, suppose I have 2 processes on the app, and one needs to tell something to the other, do I have to use AIDL ? I think it's suggested on the docs to consider using other ways: "Note: Using AIDL is necessary only if you allow clients from different applications to access your service for IPC and want to handle multithreading in your service. ...you should create your interface by implementing a Binder or...implement your interface using a Messenger. "

Comment: @androiddeveloper: "Is AIDL needed even if the service is inside the current app, yet has a different process that it runs on?" -- a bound service needs AIDL if another process will be the client of that service. The issue is not the owner of the client process. The issue is the separate process. AIDL is needed for IPC, regardless of who owns the client process.

Comment: @CommonsWare But that's not what's written on the docs. There are even tutorials that have 2 processes on the app (one is defined for the service), that talk to each other via Messenger. Example: http://codetheory.in/android-interprocess-communication-ipc-messenger-remote-bound-services/ . Or you mean that if you want binding, you need AIDL ? If so , what's the purpose of the other techniques? Messenger is just one-direction communication?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: "Or you mean that if you want binding, you need AIDL ?" -- yes. A bound service needs AIDL if another process will be the client of that service. "Messenger is just one-direction communication?" -- yes. "what's the purpose of the other techniques?" -- sometimes, a started service is sufficient, in which case you can use stuff like `Messenger`, `ResultReceiver`, `PendingIntent`, and the like to establish limited communications without the headache of a bound service and AIDL.

Comment: @CommonsWare I see. Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

**I think so if you do it will be good**

Frist of all create `Servic`

```
public class MyService extends Service {

MyReceiver receiver = new MyReceiver();
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    receiver.startAlarm(this);
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    receiver.startAlarm(this);
}

}
```

after start alarm listen to alarm create `BroadcastReceiver`

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) { 
        Log.e("Receiver", "end alarm")
    }
}


public void setAlarm(Context context) {
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(context, BootReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 10, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
}

public void cancelAlarm(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, BootReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(sender);
}
```

add manifest this

```
<service android:name=".MyService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:process=":my_service"/>

    <receiver
        android:name="MyReceiver"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```