# Android Service Starting A activity in its own process

Tags: android, process

if Android service is running in its own process say "STACKPR", and  this Service will starts a new activity, Will this activity is part of  "STACKPR" process by default or its part of application process ?

I tried the below method, but it is starting in a application process.

```
// in on start
Intent sIntent = new Intent(this, BasicActivity.class);
sIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(sIntent);
```

If it is not part of Service process, How to starts a activity which runs in that Service process ?

Comment: sew [Start a service in a separate process android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22514373/start-a-service-in-a-separate-process-android/38318003)

Answer (score 0):

By default ALL application components (Activities, Services, etc.) run in a single process.

The `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag will create a new task stack for that Activity. Think of a new task stack as a separate entry when you press the Recents button. They are both in the same process though.

To have your Service, or any application component, run in a different process use `android:process="<unique string>"`. However, this is **NOT** recommended and you can usually accomplish the same outcome using a threading model.

Please see here for more info: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html