# music pause when app killed when using service

Tags: android, service, push-notification

I am using a `Service` class to play music in the background. While I am displaying the notification bar on top, there is issue in my app. When I kill the app, the music stops for about 1 second and then it starts again. I can't figure out what's the issue.

I was following [this](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-service-example/) tutorial.

```
public class MyMusicService extends Service {

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    public MyMusicService() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        if (mediaPlayer!= null)
        {
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }
        mediaPlayer =MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.song);
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        mediaPlayer.start();

         return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

            mediaPlayer.stop();


    }
}
```

Comment: try calling mediaplayer.stop(); before the super.onDestroy();

Comment: @MATex   tried but not helping

Comment: Had this exact issue once.. I strongly recommend you use the default Android service for an audio app, this way the system will not kill your app... you'll have to read carefully and write a lot of code, but it will fix all your problems.. This is from a long and painful experience with music playing apps :) .  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-app/building-an-audio-app.html

Comment: @HedShafran Thanks but i for now i am just testing my code with help of music player,  i can' t find the bug

Comment: As you wish... This is what solved my bug at the time, and it was a really good practice as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Use onTaskRemoved on your main activity and release your mediaplayer on this event.

Answer (score 0):

According to: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html
Change

```
START_STICKY
```

to

```
START_NOT_STICKY
```

---

EDIT:

The issue with music stopping for a while is connected with the fact that you run app and service in the same process. And 'killing app' means stopping the whole process bound to it. What you need to do is to run your service in seperate process:

[Start a service in a separate process android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22514373/start-a-service-in-a-separate-process-android)

Comment: i also tried this but music stops when app is killed,...anyways thanks

Comment: Oh I tought that is exactly what you want. So what's a problem anyway? You do not want to stop the music at all?

Comment: no....the music should continuously play even if i kill the app...and its playing but when i kill the app there i pause of 1 sec before the music starts again

Comment: @AvadaKedavra try to start media player in onCreate instead of on start command coz when you kill your app the service restarted and on start commmand is called again

Comment: @AvadaKedavra its because your service is STICKY

Comment: applying in the onCreate has the same issue...i will try another method

Answer (score 0):

That tutorial shows you how to build a BACKGROUND service, which can get killed by the system. To play music you should use a FOREGROUND service.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground