# Widget stops updating after closing app

Tags: android, service, widget

In an `AppWidgetProvider` class, I have a simple `CountDownTimer` running.

```
object : CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

    override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
        val appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context)
        val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName,R.layout.view_group)
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.m_text_view,"seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000)
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[0], views)
    }

    override fun onFinish() {
        // Do nothing
    }
}.start()
```

This updates the corresponding widget (`appWidgetIds[0]`) as expected, but this is only the case while the app is open. When I swipe off the app in the recents menu, I.e. closing it, the widget stops updating.

I have tried using a separate service too, but same result. Presumably because the service is not a foreground service, and I don't want to have a persistent notification so I can't use a foreground service.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the answer.

> In the on the `onStartCommand` method of the service, return `START_STICKY` flag. This will tell the OS, if for any reason the service closes, run it again when you have enough resources.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35684523/812919)
[more info](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#ExtendingService)

On restart, you can get all widget ids as follows:

```
ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context,MyWidgetProvider.class);
int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
```

[source](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidWidgets/article.html#exercise-update-widget-via-a-service)

**EDIT**

**Just so you know, in versions of android greater than API 23, even the `START_STICKY` flag isn't enough to get the OS to restart the service.**

**I've decided to skip this feature because it won't work in future versions of android.**

Answer (score 2):

> When I swipe off the app in the recents menu, I.e. closing it, the widget stops updating.

That generally terminates your process, at which point your `CountDownTimer` no longer exists.

> I have tried using a separate service too, but same result

That would not necessarily prevent your process from being terminated, though it might help get you a process back faster. However, on Android 8.0+, your service would be stopped after a minute.

Doing work every 30 seconds in the background is fairly evil from a battery consumption standpoint, which is why it is impractical on modern versions of Android.

Comment: Surely it cant be impossible, there must be a way. I've seen other apps successfully implement this functionality. I.e. widget count down timers.

Comment: @daka: Many of those other apps will suffer from the same limitation that you are seeing. A few might spawn the service in a separate process, but that might not fix your task-swiping problem on all devices, and even then the app will still have limits (Doze mode/app standby on Android 6.0+, 1-minute service lifetime on Android 8.0+, etc.). It also does not change the underlying problems with your app (e.g., having to hold a `WakeLock` to keep the device awake constantly, so your `CountDownTimer` continues running) that harm users.

Comment: Okay, I get that there is a lot going against me android 6+, but I just tried it on android 4.0 and I get the same issue.

Comment: @daka: You can try having your service run in a separate process and see if it gives you better results on older versions of Android.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction, I found the answer.

Comment: I've posted it below

Comment: Now I have an issue where if the widget exists, and _then_ then app is started and closed, the widget service does not restart.

Comment: This issue only affects android versions greater than 6.0 (API 23). I think I will rethink what I wish to offer in my app, because it seems the frequent updating of the widget doesn't play well with the latest (and probably future) versions of android.