# Using mqtt to send push notification , not working when swiped from recent apps

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, android-service, mqtt

using mqtt for push notification in android with following libs :

```
implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.1.1'
implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.1.0'
```

i followed [this](https://wildanmsyah.wordpress.com/2017/05/11/mqtt-android-client-tutorial/) tutorial , **the problem is it works properly when app is open , but when it is swiped from recent apps , it stops working and I can't receive push notifications anymore** 
 ***any help is appreciated***

solutions i tried :

**first solution** : created a service and simply created a mqttclient in it , but after swiping from recent apps didn't work anymore

```
public class MqttService extends Service {

    public MqttService(Context context) {
        super();
    }

    public MqttService() {
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        PahoDemo paho = new Paho(getApplicationContext(), "myTopic");

        return START_STICKY;
    }


    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {

        Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.restart");
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.restart");
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

PahoDemo :

```
public class Paho implements MqttCallback {
    String topic;
    MqttClient client;
    Context context;

    public Paho(Context context, String topic) {
        this.context = context;
        this.topic = topic;
        try {
            client = new MqttClient(StaticValue.getBROKER(), MqttClient.generateClientId(), persistence);
            MqttConnectOptions connOpts = new MqttConnectOptions();
            connOpts.setCleanSession(true);
            client.connect(connOpts);
            client.setCallback(this);
            if (topic != null) {
                client.subscribe(topic);
            }
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            System.out.println("error: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void connectionLost(Throwable cause) {
    }
    @Override
    public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
        Log.i("mqtt", "messageArrived ");
    }

    @Override
    public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken token) {
        Log.i("mqtt", token + "");
    }

}
```

**second solution**:

added the below line to manifest :

```
 <service android:name="org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService" />
```

called this helper class from mainactivty's Oncreate :

```
public class MqttHelper {
    public MqttAndroidClient mqttAndroidClient;

    final String serverUri = "myBrokerUri";

    final String clientId = MqttClient.generateClientId();
    final String subscriptionTopic = "myTopic";


    public MqttHelper(Context context){
        mqttAndroidClient = new MqttAndroidClient(context, serverUri, clientId);
        mqttAndroidClient.setCallback(new MqttCallbackExtended() {
            @Override
            public void connectComplete(boolean b, String s) {
                Log.w("mqtt", s);
            }

            @Override
            public void connectionLost(Throwable throwable) {

            }

            @Override
            public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws Exception {
                Log.w("Mqtt", mqttMessage.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken iMqttDeliveryToken) {

            }
        });
        connect();
    }

    public void setCallback(MqttCallbackExtended callback) {
        mqttAndroidClient.setCallback(callback);
    }

    private void connect(){
        MqttConnectOptions mqttConnectOptions = new MqttConnectOptions();
        mqttConnectOptions.setAutomaticReconnect(true);
        mqttConnectOptions.setCleanSession(true);

        try {

            mqttAndroidClient.connect(mqttConnectOptions, null, new IMqttActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {

                    subscribeToTopic();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                    Log.w("Mqtt", "Failed to connect to: " + serverUri + exception.toString());
                }
            });


        } catch (MqttException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private void subscribeToTopic() {
        try {
            mqttAndroidClient.subscribe(subscriptionTopic, 0, null, new IMqttActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                    Log.w("Mqtt","Subscribed!");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                    Log.w("Mqtt", "Subscribed fail!");
                }
            });

        } catch (MqttException ex) {
            System.err.println("Exceptionst subscribing");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**that's all i did since tow days ago . if someone has any ideas , please mention .**

Comment: Where do you implement your client? If you want to subscribe a topic when app is closed you will have to create a service, but to make it alive you will have to keep showing notification about that.

Comment: at first i wrote my own service , but not working when app swiped from recent apps , second used  org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService but got same answer , plz explain your solution more obvious .

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/35684523, if you will still have problem with your implementation of service, just update your question and i will try to help to solve your problem.

Comment: i knew that , if you have a solution please post . thanks in advance .

Comment: You need to show us what you've tried and we will help you fix it, we will not just wholesale provide a solution

Comment: ok , I added the code , take a look please .

Answer (score 0):

**when messageArrived is called , you shouldn't use something you don't access to** . for example if you wanna check app is in foreground , you may use context , this way your logic may doesn't work properly , so make sure you do what you can do in messageArrived and if you aren't sure the objects you use are available do it another way  (also be careful about connectinLost )