# Is start a service in another process no longer supported in Android?

Tags: android, android-service

I have a service

```
<service android:name="com.example.myapplication_sync.MainService" />
```

The service is simply

```
class MainService: Service() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        Log.d("Tracking", "Service started")
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }
}
```

I can start the service using

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    Intent(this, MainService::class.java).also { intent ->
        startService(intent)
    }
}
```

But if the process is

```
<service android:name="com.example.myapplication_sync.MainService" 
    android:process=":myDifferentProcess"
/>
```

I can't seem to start the service anymore. Is this no longer work now, or I miss something?

**Note: I have compile and target SDK/API of 30, and I'm running on Android Device API SDK 30 on emulator**

Comment: On starting another serive process https://stackoverflow.com/a/38318003/3286489

Comment: You should mention what targetSDK and OS version/environment you are testing on.