# cancel AsyncTask on stopping service

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask

I am using

```
Intent I=new  Intent(Myactivity.this,MyService.class);
```

intent to start and stop a service.I have a *AsycTask* inside this service which wouldn't stop until the task get completed or application is closed. To stop *Asynctask* on stopping service I have tried calling **onDestroyed** method as

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (task!=null) {
        if(!task.isCancelled()) {
            task.onCancelled();
            task.cancel(true);
        }
    }
    isRunning=false;
    System.out.println("service destroyed");
    super.onDestroy();
    stopSelf();
}
```

(which I think is not triggered because the "*service destroyed*" message is not printed after calling **stopService(I)** or even when task is finished).
Next thing I tried was making *Asyctask* class static and call **cancel(true)** method from **Myactivity** that too didn't help.Any helpful suggestion apreciated.

Comment: Can you paste your AsyncTask as well?

Comment: @WarrenFaith Since my AsyncTask is a bit long so please see [here](http://pastebin.com/bgwEfrUV)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you need to check within your AsyncTask if it is set to cancel. Check [here the AsyncTask documentation, topic "Usage"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

```
// at one point in your doDownload() method check for cancel state
if (isCancelled()) {
    // do a break or just return or what ever you need for a clean exit
}
```

I am not sure how you exactly try to stop the service but basically [that should work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9964395/180538).

Comment: It did work after I clean project and yes I have called the same method to stop the service. Thanks .

Comment: can use like this also http://www.quicktips.in/correct-way-to-cancel-an-asynctask-in-android/