# how to stop Services which detect changes in firebase realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-service

I want to retrieve data continuously from firebase realtime database. I have made a service for that purpose but, the service do not stops on calling `stopService`. I want to stop service when i got the appropriate data. Please help.

I tried

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,BackgroundSoundService.class);  
stopService(intent);
```

But this didn't not work. What else i need to do to stop this service?

```
 @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
   IniTializeSpeech(getApplicationContext());
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mDatabase.child("objectsData").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           String ss =(String) dataSnapshot.getValue();
           Log.i("OnDataChange",ss);
            t1.speak(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only interested in getting the data once, you can instead use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`:

```
mDatabase.child("objectsData").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(...
```

---

If you have a more complex condition, you can use your current code to register. But to later stop the event listener from responding to data changes, you need to [remove that listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#detach_listeners).

To do this, you first keep a reference to the listener when you register it:

```
ValueEventListener myListener = mDatabase.child("objectsData").addValueEventListener(...
```

And then you can later remove it with:

```
mDatabase.child("objectsData").removeEventListener(myListener)
```

Comment: what about stoping the service? by the way thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you asking [how to stop a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9964356/how-to-stop-running-services)?

Comment: I want to stop this service but stopService() method is unable to stop it. What else I need to do to stop this service since stopService() is unable to stop.