# Android: Stop/start service created in onCreate()

Tags: java, android, android-service

I currently have a service that is started within the onCreate method of an activity using:

```
Intent intentService = new Intent(this, MainService.class);
this.startService(intentService);
```

I need to now be able to stop this service on a button press and restart it again on another button press, however I am unsure how to stop this service and start it again out side of the onCreate method.

I guess I would need to start the service in a different way than what I am currently doing? But I am unsure on the best method for this.

I had looks at [stop service in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555765/stop-service-in-android) but their method of starting the service seems not to work within onCreate.

A more complete over view of my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            lock = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.lock);
            unlock = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.unlock);

            lock.setOnClickListener(btn_lock);
            unlock.setOnClickListener(btn_unlock);

            unlock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            lock.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            Intent intentService = new Intent(this, MainService.class);
            this.startService(intentService);

        }
private OnClickListener btn_lock = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
                unlock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                lock.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        }
    };
private OnClickListener btn_unlock = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
                unlock.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                lock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

When ever you want to start a service all you need is

```
 startService(new Intent(this, MainService.class));
```

And to Stop a service anytime just call

```
stopService(new Intent(this, MainService.class));
```

Remember service needs to be declared in AndroidManifest.xml. As you said that your service is working. I'm sure you have done that. 
Still AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".MainService" />
```

Comment: EDIT seems that this only works in onCreate the code will not work in the onclick listener

Comment: yes. But try stopping a service first and then start it. It wouldn't crash if the service was already stopped

Comment: Seems to not work within the onclick listener assuming the this needs to be changed to something else?

Comment: in OnClick Listener instead of `this` use `MainActivity.this`.