# Android Service NOT dying when app is killed

Tags: java, android

### The Issue

Ultimately I want to run the following code whenever my app dies:

```
playerNotificationManager.setPlayer(null);
```

### My Setup

I've seen a lot of questions asking how to keep a service alive, but I want my service to die and it keeps hanging around in the background.

I have an app using ExoPlayer with a service to continue playing audio in the background when you minimize the app. The service looks basically like so:

**PlayerService.java**:

```
package com.blueframetech.bfsdk.adapters;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;

import com.blueframetech.bfsdk.R;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.Player;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerNotificationManager;

public class PlayerService extends Service
{

    public  Player                    player;
    private PlayerNotificationManager playerNotificationManager;

    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        final Context context = this;

        playerNotificationManager = PlayerNotificationManager.createWithNotificationChannel(
            context, "Channel ID", R.string.app_name, 0,
            new PlayerNotificationManager.MediaDescriptionAdapter() {
                @Override
                public String getCurrentContentTitle ( Player player )
                {
                    return null;
                }

                @Nullable
                @Override
                public PendingIntent createCurrentContentIntent ( Player player )
                {
                    return null;
                }

                @Nullable
                @Override
                public String getCurrentContentText ( Player player )
                {
                    return null;
                }

                @Nullable
                @Override
                public Bitmap getCurrentLargeIcon (
                    Player player, PlayerNotificationManager.BitmapCallback callback
                )
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        );

        playerNotificationManager.setNotificationListener(new PlayerNotificationManager.NotificationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onNotificationStarted ( int notificationId, Notification notification )
            {
                startForeground(0, notification);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNotificationCancelled ( int notificationId )
            {
                stopSelf();
            }
        });
    }

    private final IPlayerInterface.Stub mBinder = new IPlayerInterface.Stub() {
        public void setPlayer ( int playerId ) throws RemoteException
        {
            if (playerId < 0)
            {
                playerNotificationManager.setPlayer(null);
            }
            else
            {
                player = ExoPlayerSingleton.getInstance(playerId);
                playerNotificationManager.setPlayer(player);
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind ( Intent intent )
    {
        return mBinder;
    }

}
```

To spin up the service, I do the following:

**PlayerActivity.java**:

```
        playerId = ExoPlayerSingleton.createInstance();
        playerView = findViewById(R.id.player_view);

        serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection()
        {
            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected ( ComponentName name, IBinder service )
            {
                playerService = (IPlayerInterface) service;
            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected ( ComponentName name )
            {
                playerService = null;
            }
        };

        context.bindService(
            new Intent(getContext(), PlayerService.class),
            serviceConnection,
            Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE
        );
```

Then in my activity's `onDestroy` method, I added the following to avoid leaking the service when the back button was pressed:

```
getContext().unbindService(serviceConnection);
```

I also have an AIDL file and some code in `onPause` and `onResume` to switch between the `PlayerView` and the `PlayerService` (switching which is bound to the ExoPlayer instance) -- and that all seems to work as expected:

```
playerView.setPlayer(null);
playerService.setPlayer(playerId);
// ...
playerService.setPlayer(null);
playerView.setPlayer(ExoPlayerSingleton.getInstance(playerId));
```

### What's Happening

If I minimize the app, the service takes over playback, the notification appears, and I continue to hear audio. However if I then go to the task manager and kill my app, the audio cuts out. **This is fine**. The issue is that after the audio cuts out, the notification remains open, and the service is still running in the background doing nothing. This is because the `onDestroy` method of my activity isn't run when the app is killed this way.

Once I've gotten into this state, there are only two ways to kill the notification:

1. Restart my app
2. Go into Settings, find my app, and select "Force Stop"

How can I tell my service to die when my app dies? I don't like this zombie notification hanging around.

Comment: May be this link help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555765/stop-service-in-android

Comment: @SaboorSiddique Unfortunately that link doesn't help. In their example the app is still open and they're using the interaction with a button view to trigger a call to `stopService`. In my case, I want to stop the service when my app is killed - and there is no callback for that which I can find. I tried `onStop`, `onDestroy`, and even the service's `onUnbind` - but nothing was called automatically when the app died