# How to close a service from an activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, service

I am trying to make an app that has only one activity and when you press a button the app is closed but a service remains in the background. However, I want to have an option button (in onCreateOptionsMenu) called 'Close App' so when you click it the Activity is `finish();` and the service is killed. The problem is that I know how to close the Activity, but not how to kill the service from the Activity. Here is part of my code (I omited couple basic methods for simplicity):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        bDone.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void Onclick(){
        Intent serv = new Intent(Main.this, Bground.class);
        startService(serv);

        finish();
}


public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.closeApp) {
            finish();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I have tried putting the `Intent serv;` as a global variable and writing `stopService(serv);` right above the `finish();` in the onOptionsItemSeected but it gives me an error.

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of error? Post stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Try  **unbindService()** in your *onStop()*.

Comment: Using 'serv' as the argument or using no argument: "The method unbindService(ServiceConnection) in the type ContextWrapper is not applicable for the arguments (Intent)".

Comment: Look at this example please : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341667/bind-unbind-service-example-android

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved it this way

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.closeApp) {
        stopService(new Intent(Main.this, Bground.class));
        finish();
    }
```

Just adding `stopService(new Intent(Main.this, Bground.class));`

Thanks to this post: [How to call stopservice() method of Service class from the calling activity class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165190/how-to-call-stopservice-method-of-service-class-from-the-calling-activity-clas)