# How to update variable inside of a service and execute based off of the status

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am learning Java and Android development. Right now I am making an app that once launched will create a service. Then I want the service to do things based on a button that I press within my app.

This is my service class.

```
public class ServiceClass extends Service {

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        // Issue is here. I cannot use findViewById
        Button start_stop_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        start_stop_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        // stop the wifi manager
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

My thought was I could just set a listener so when I press the button the onClick() would execute. But that wouldn't work since the service is not attached to any activity to know what the id "button1" is.

So then I thought about keeping a class variable and just updating it. These seems fairly simple but then I am not sure how I would be able to keep the service checking for the status of the variable to change. I could put it in a for loop to continue checking but I feel like a better way exists.

tldr; I have an app that kicks off a service. I want my app to be able to be closed and the service still run. But I want to have a start/stop button in my app that will trigger the service.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a button as such to explicitly stop a service because it will be stopped automatically when the job inside `onStartCommand` is done

If you want manual control for the service inside your `Activity` where your button actually is then you can use `stopService` and `startService` methods

You can find a detailed explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43212570/9722336)

Also Service is meant to be Ui-less, so you can't do something related to the UI in the service, that's not what it is meant for. You can pop a notification and on tap you can start your activity which can give you access to the button if you're wishing to do something like that