# Stopping an Android service (when back to the foreground) not working

Tags: android, kotlin, service

Here is an issue I am facing when using a service in an Android app to play audio in the background.

The audio plays as expected in the background, and the app has a stop button that should be used to stop the audio play when the app comes back to the foreground. And this button is not working.

I use a class instance variable *serviceIntent* like this:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    .....
    private var serviceIntent:Intent? = null
    .....
}
```

Here is how the service is started from the *onStop()* method of the main activity.

```
override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    .....

    serviceIntent = Intent(this, AudioService::class.java)
    serviceIntent?.let {
        it.putExtra("audioPath", audioPath)
        it.putExtra("timePosit", playTimeStamp.toString())
        it.putExtra("playMode", playMode)
        .....
        startForegroundService(it)
    }
}
```

And here is how I try to stop the service when the stop button is tapped (but this is not working):
(The two first lines are obviously only for debugging)

```
stopBtn.setOnClickListener {
    if (serviceIntent == null) println("There is no +++serviceIntent+++")
    else println("Trying to stop +++serviceIntent+++")

    serviceIntent?.let {stopService(it)}
}
```

I can see the message: "Trying to stop +++serviceIntent+++"
indicating that *serviceIntent* is not null, but the audio playing does not stop.

Any relevant feedback by some more experienced user will be much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/43212570/6819340

Comment: Yes, looking at the post of your link led me to a solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop the audio service as well before you stop your service.if you are using audio manager try stopping like this and pass listener _audioFocusChangeListener of OnAudioFocusChangeListener interface.

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        audioManager.abandonAudioFocus(_audioFocusChangeListener);
```